# Motorola Milestone problems

Tags: motorola-milestone, bugs

Before I start, please let me say I've tried pretty much everything, including, of course asking my providers for a new phone, but it didn't work. I also posted a similar question on a programmer's site but they couldn't/wouldn't help me. So here it is: I got the Motorola Milestone and it just has so many bugs, it's ridiculous. When I searched online I saw people complaining exactly about the same issues.

1. Phone switches off randomly, sometimes during a call.
2. Phone switches ON randomly, sometimes during a meeting (!)
3. Music from the MP3 player turns on randomly, so I always have to turn the volume off before turning the application off.

I also tried upgrading etc, but nothing helped.

:/

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered random OFF problem a couple of times and it seemed to be always related to the connection with a Bluetooth equipment. For the random ON problem I would recommend shutting down the sound and keeping the device ON every time. The random music activation should have been corrected with the latest firmware update. In my case, the firmware version 2.1-update1 corrected the random music activation. I would recommend that you make sure all your firmware updates have been done.

These are not the best solutions but that is all I have been able to find. Let's hope the next update to Android 2.2 will correct all these issues once and for all.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Motorola has screwed up royally.  I recommend a custom ROM from XDA: http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=670

Answer (score 1):

I recommend everyone CyanogenMod 6:
http://www.cyanogenmod.com/
http://android.doshaska.net/cm6

The latest version CM 6.1.2 is based on Android 2.2.1 with 2.6.32.9 kernel.

I had a lot of problems at offical firmware (Android 2.1): random reboot, spontaneous music playing, gtalk is not worked, bugs with media scanner which cause 100% CPU usage all time.

I didn't found any bugs at CM 6. Even more my motorola became much faster and less use battery .

Comment: Me too recommend this. I am using cm6 on my milestone. Everything works and is smooth too...